# MinGW/MSYS shell colors

Tags: shell, colors, mingw, msys

I'd like for my makefile output to be color-coded.

But I can't get the ANSI color codes to work on this terminal. It should be possible though, `ls --color` gives me colorful output, and my shell prompt is also colored:

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:\w\007 \033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\w\033[0m\] $
```

I suspect maybe the first section puts the terminal in a special mode so that it will accept color codes. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it.

The command to use is `echo -e`.

So, in the makefile:

```
foo.o: foo.c
    @echo -e "\033[32mCompiling foo.c\033[0m"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

I would imagine this works just fine in bash as well.

Comment: Though i'll point out that I still haven't figured out how to get an arbitrary program to switch the terminal into the correct mode to interpret the color signals. Currently to make my unit tests print out all pretty I have to pipe the command through cat, for example.

Comment: and for the uninitiated, piping output through cat adds a layer of buffer latency. It's not a problem for a build script's output but if you've got something interactive, it's more or less horrific.

Comment: I'm using `printf` instead. It works great and you get the additional interpolation of strings, nice to use with generic message functions and what not, you can assign stdout values to a variable with the minus v (`-v VAR`) option and generally it is considered more portable than `echo`. Though I am not sure if it is present native in MinGW since I am running GoW (GNU on Windows) and a few other win32 compiled *nix tools I took to this system. Oh, and no obligated `-e` switch either, it just works as `printf "\033[32mFoo\033[0m"` or `printf "\033[32m%s\033[0m" "foo"` both are valid.